# JQuery toggleClass slide up two divs effect

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a website that will be retrieving a lot of data for the user and instead of pagination i need to create a single page out put that will be divided into sections by categories - these will all have one class. I need to `slideUp` and `toggleClass` the categories upon contact - the top category floated.

This is the portion that deals with that, any ideas on how i can best implement this (they need to push up each other, then toggleClass - i dont want to use the slideUp as it hides the class) :

```
first = $bc(".title")[current_first];
$bc(first).addClass('float_title');

settings.first_title = current_first;
f_Ypos = Math.floor($bc(first).position().top);
//console.log("f_Y: "+f_Ypos+" | settings.first_title: "+settings.first_title);

settings.next_title = current_first+1;
next = $bc(".title")[settings.next_title];
n_Ypos = Math.floor($bc(next).position().top/2);
console.log("f_Ypos: "+f_Ypos+" | f_Yposx4: "+((f_Ypos*5)+2)+" n_Ypos: "+n_Ypos );

if(f_Ypos == n_Ypos  || ((f_Ypos*5)+2) >= n_Ypos) {
    $bc(first).toggleClass('float_title', 250, "easeOutSine").animate({top: "-1%"});
    $bc(next).toggleClass('float_title', 250, "easeOutSine").animate({top: "1%"});

    settings.prev_title = settings.first_title;       
    prev = $bc(".title")[settings.prev_title];

    settings.first_title++;

    p_Ypos = Math.floor($bc(prev).position().top/2);
    console.log("prev: "+p_Ypos+" | first: "+f_Ypos+" next: "+n_Ypos);
}
```

`$bc` is the JQuery object - `jQuery.noConflict()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have enough points to comment hence why I write here... have you considered http://api.jquery.com/slideup/ and the "progress" and "start" options?

You could have your toggle performed when the slideup starts, and using progress, prevent the slideup from fully completeing (and thus not hiding). I have not tried this approach but if I had the time, that would be something I would look into.

Comment: Awesome, interesting, was doubting it but it worked. Thanks

Comment: Hi @fiprojects client is not to happy with the way the effects execute - any help in implementing a pushup animation? basically the current floating title should be "pushed away" once the next title 'touches' it (the current),  and (the next) become the current floating title.

Comment: Your OP includes code that I *think* I understand - My understanding is you check the Y position of your tile and if it 'touches' another tile, another animation event should take place.  This would be my approach.  Thus... I suspect what your client is looking for is beyond my experience/skillset - sorry. Can you find any online examples on any website that show the effect your client hopes for? That would help others to help you as opposed to they making suggestions which are later found to be unacceptable. Sorry I cannot offer more.

Comment: Hi @fiprojects
I just found this site http://brianhadaway.github.io/iOSList/ is does the job but they dont example their code - would have been nice to use that. Any so that plugin effect is exactly what i would want to integrate into my solution, let me know what you think?